# Foreign key auto assigned on RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 4 models (`Users`, `Post`, `Comments`, `Value`) like this:
One user can post something, and someone can comment this post. After that, another user can add a numeric value from 0 to 10 to the comment.

I have done the relation between `Users` and `Post` helping me with the rails tutorial, but now i don't know the next step.

Comment: I don't get your question, what have you tried ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can set up a relation between that value you would like to assign (lets call it rating) and 2 other models.

Based on what you said I guess your relations (associations) would look like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :post
  has_many :comment
  has_many :rating, :through => :comment
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comment
  has_many :rating, :through => :comment
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
  has_many :rating
end

class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :comment
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user, :through => :comment
end
```

Read more about it [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association)

Comment: nearly right, but you'd need to use the plural for a has_many relationship - eg. `has_many :posts`.

Comment: sorry, also you can't have `belongs_to :user, :through => :comment`. That's not a problem though, because there doesn't need to be a relationship between user and rating, unless I'm misinterpreting the requirements

Comment: thank you omnikron, it was a stab in the dark form my side, probably you or others can correct it